# Is $\{ aa^nb^n : n \ge 0 \}$ a non-regular language?

Tags: regular-languages, finite-automata

I know that $\{a^nb^n : n\geq 0\}$ is a non-regular language. Would adding another $a$ so that it is $\{ a^{n+1}b^n : n \geq 0\}$ change things? Would this still be a non-regular language?

Answer (score 1):

You are asking if $a^{n+1}b^n$ is a regular language.

First try to think about the reason why $a^nb^n$ isn't regular.

What would make $n+1$ appearances of $a$ and then $n$ appearances of $b$ in the input different if you can't check $a^nb^n$?

What have you tried so far?

Check this reference
https://www.cs.wcupa.edu/rkline/fcs/re-pump.html